# Shopify - get price, stock on hand hand in realtime from external database

Tags: api, shopify

My company would like to sell products through the Shopify Platform, but be they want to be able to get their prices and stock levels from an external data base.  We have developers that know how to create an API, but we do not quite understand how to set up a private app to do this.

For instance, we want to make an ajax call to this endpoint **www.{ourDomain}/shopify/getPrice.html?Part=UserRequestedPart** and the endpoint would return some JSON or XML data which I would expect to parse and display in Shopify.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a [private app](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/private-apps) with `write_products` and `write_inventory` [scopes](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/access-scopes).
2. Access your endpoint to get current prices/inventory from your external database.
3. Update Shopify product prices/inventory using Shopify API.

   - Use [Product Variant](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/product-variant#update-2020-01) to update prices.
   - Use [Inventory Level](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/inventory/inventorylevel#set-2020-01) endpoint to update the quantity.

More details can be found here: [Shopify Admin API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api)